# How to resolve "Execution failed for task':flutter_keyboard_visibility:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'" error?

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

I'm getting

> "Execution failed for task':flutter_keyboard_visibility:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'"

error while building the project. I've been working on this project for a while without a problem. The only thing I've done was a `flutter upgrade`. I did not add, delete a dependency or anything. I'm experiencing this issue on every single Flutter project now. When I try to build and run a native Android application, everything works as expected. I'm suspecting that Flutter cannot find Android SDK or similar to this but I can see that the path to Android SDK is as it should be. Below is the full version of errors Android Studio is giving me.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
error: error reading /Users/sametsahin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/469d369e7a7ea2b0f6b2822cfc8a6ec0cc99e962/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.jar; error in opening zip file
error: error reading /Users/sametsahin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695/469d369e7a7ea2b0f6b2822cfc8a6ec0cc99e962/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-2994f7e1e682039464cb25e31a78b86a3c59b695.jar; error in opening zip file
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:11: error: package io.flutter.app does not exist
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
                     ^
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:12: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel;
                               ^
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:13: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel.EventSink;
                                            ^
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:14: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel.StreamHandler;
                                            ^
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:15: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar;
                                              ^
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
public class KeyboardVisibilityPlugin implements StreamHandler, Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                                                 ^
  symbol: class StreamHandler
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    EventSink eventsSink;
    ^
  symbol:   class EventSink
  location: class KeyboardVisibilityPlugin
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
    Registrar registrar;
    ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: class KeyboardVisibilityPlugin
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    KeyboardVisibilityPlugin(Registrar registrar) {
                             ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: class KeyboardVisibilityPlugin
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:100: error: cannot find symbol
    public static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
                                    ^
  symbol:   class Registrar
  location: class KeyboardVisibilityPlugin
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:113: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onListen(Object arguments, final EventSink eventsSink) {
                                                 ^
  symbol:   class EventSink
  location: class KeyboardVisibilityPlugin
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
        if (activity instanceof FlutterActivity) {
                                ^
  symbol:   class FlutterActivity
  location: class KeyboardVisibilityPlugin
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
        if (activity instanceof FlutterActivity) {
                                ^
  symbol:   class FlutterActivity
  location: class KeyboardVisibilityPlugin
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
        if (activity instanceof FlutterActivity) {
                                ^
  symbol:   class FlutterActivity
  location: class KeyboardVisibilityPlugin
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:102: error: cannot find symbol
        final EventChannel eventChannel = new EventChannel(registrar.messenger(), STREAM_CHANNEL_NAME);
              ^
  symbol:   class EventChannel
  location: class KeyboardVisibilityPlugin
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:102: error: cannot find symbol
        final EventChannel eventChannel = new EventChannel(registrar.messenger(), STREAM_CHANNEL_NAME);
                                              ^
  symbol:   class EventChannel
  location: class KeyboardVisibilityPlugin
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:112: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/sametsahin/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_keyboard_visibility-0.7.0/android/src/main/java/com/flutter/keyboardvisibility/KeyboardVisibilityPlugin.java:123: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
18 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_keyboard_visibility:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Also when I check the build.gradle file found in danef_dictionary/android/app/build.gradle
I realize that GradleException is red and says

> Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException'

when I hover over it.
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by making following changes:

In Android build.gradle
Changed
classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`
to
classpath `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'`

Changed

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
```

to

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
```

In android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Changed

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```